# Convert column with multiple unique rows to matrix table using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have this table as input

| Likelihood | Impact | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Very Likely | Minimal​ | Low |
| Very Likely | Moderate | High |
| Very Likely | Severe​ | High |
| Likely​ | Minimal​ | Low |
| Likely​ | Moderate | High |
| Likely​ | Severe​ | High |
| Possible​ | Minimal​ | Low |
| Possible​ | Moderate | Medium |
| Possible​ | Severe​ | High |
| Unlikely​ | Minimal​ | Low |
| Unlikely​ | Moderate | Low |
| Unlikely​ | Severe​ | Medium |
| Very Unlikely​ | Minimal​ | Low |
| Very Unlikely | Moderate | Low |
| Very Unlikely | Severe | Low |

I was unable to get as my expectation. I am getting NULL values for `Minimal` and `Severe` column.

I ran the SQL

```
SELECT Likelihood, Minimal, Moderate, Severe
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM MYTABLE
) AS S
PIVOT (MAX(Score) for Impact in (Minimal, Moderate, Severe)) AS Pivot_Table
```

I need output as

| Likelihood | Minimal | Moderate | Severe |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Very Likely | Low | High | High |
| Likely | Low | High | High |
| Possible | Low | Medium | High |
| Unlikely | Low | Low | Medium |
| Very Unlikely | Low | Low | Low |

Any suggestions?

Comment: On first glance what you've got looks good... To check, are you sure the values in your `Impact` column are '`Minimal'` and '`Severe'`; i.e. if there were leading or trailing spaces in the text that may cause issues.  Also, what's the type of your impact column (as I notice you imply that `'Moderate'` works / that's the longest word, so if it's `nchar(8)` rather than `nvarchar(8)` the system may be adding trailing spaces?...

Comment: Actually - it's similar to what I suggested... Copy-pasting your sample data into the [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) editor shows the issue.  To see it run `select unicode(cast(substring('Minimal​', 8,1) as char))`

Answer (score 1):

The issue's down to special characters hiding in your data / meaning that the column's value isn't `Minimal`, but `MinimalX`, where `X` is a zero width space.

You can see this on this page - view the page's source & navigate to your sample data / look what appears after the values that are causing you issues, but doesn't appear after those values which aren't.

[image: Zero Width Space following the Minimal value]

You can also see this clearly by running this over your columns / on text copied from your columns.  You'd expect values 32 (or error) and 7, but you get 63 and 8: `select unicode(cast(substring('Minimal​', 8,1) as char)), len('Minimal​')`

[image: Screenshot of char code and length of the field]

And if you paste your data into a suitable text editor (or [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)) which shows special characters, this is flagged up quickly:

[image: DB Fiddle showing special characters]